# Is there a standard way to detect scheme implementations?

Tags: scheme

There exist many different Scheme implementations, some of which may come with more built-in features (or quirks) than others. Suppose one wants to write a piece of Scheme code that is portable across as many Scheme implementations as practical. Is there a standard way to detect which Scheme implementation is running the code?

(By "standard way", I mean common practise, or as specified by a Scheme standard).

Comment: Off the top of my head, `cond-expand` from R7RS small supports this. That, of course, depends on running on an R7RS-conformant Scheme implementation.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of systems that people have assembled for writing portable Scheme code; for instance, I believe that Dorai Sitaram's SLaTeX has a system for this, and I think Oleg Kiselyov's SXML work also had something similar.

Many people eventually give up on writing portable Scheme :).

Answer (score 1):

There have been efforts to detect differences between implementations. One such effort:

http://www.willdonnelly.net/blog/runtime-scheme-detection/

However I am not sure I would bother.

Comment: updated link: http://www.willdonnelly.net/blog/2009-03-14-runtime-scheme-detection/